# Use culture information for date format in SharePoint 2013 publishing page layouts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, angularjs

I am facing an issue with displaying the locale based date format in publishing page out.

I have this code in page layout :

```
<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="ArticleStartDate" runat="server" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" />
```

Can anyone please suggest on how to modify the code to display date locale wise.

Answer (score 0):

> It could be achieved by setting the "LocaleId" attribute of the
>   DateTimeField.
>
> Also you can disable time display by setting “DateOnly” attribute to
>   True.
>
> ```
> <SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField FieldName="4aaf3b75-d54b-4198-b100-bd3aee42224a" LocaleId="1052" DateOnly="true" runat="server" />
> ```
>
> `LocaleId=“1052”` stands for the format which is you want.

Kindly [check here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/503f0b50-8228-4c2e-b555-42aac7de668d/format-sharepointwebcontrolsdatetimefield?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) for more details

Comment: I am using i18n folder for all locale, it has to be auto changing with the respective culture information, thus i am not able to use any specific localeid

Comment: I have just taken **1052** for **an example**, So please find your locale ID from this link...https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc824907(v=office.14).aspx#BKMK_LocaleIDs

Comment: Did you tried it? Is that working for you?

Comment: I have to make it work for all locale. Like it should not depend on any particular locale. That's the issue.

Comment: Than i think you need to remove **LocaleId** from the control itself. BTW Glad to help you.

Comment: Did you managed to achieve your desired date format?